# Unable to get any data from the GET method

Tags: angular, ionic3, mean-stack

I'm unable to get any data from the `GET` method. I have a page called `job.ts` In that page I'm calling a method which is in another provider/service `ts` file.

```
` // This part of the code is from the provider/service .ts file.
getSavedJobList(userId) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.get(this.db_url + 'savedjobList/' + userId,{headers: headers})
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data 
    },(err: any) => console.log(err));
  }

// this part of the code is from the job.ts file
async getSavedJobs() {
    let id = await this.profileId();
    this.jobService.getSavedJobList(id).then((list: any) => {
      for (let job of list) {
        this.savedjobs.push(job);
      }
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      console.log('err in getting the saved jobs '+ err);
    });
  }
} `
```

Here no action is taking place.

Comment: could you be more specific? what kind of no data are you recieving? is it an empty json object or? could you as well check your network traffic in the browser and see what kind of error code you recieve from this if there is any?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm why not return the request to job.ts and subscribe here to the response? Try this:

```
getSavedJobList(userId) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.get(this.db_url + 'savedjobList/' + userId,{headers: headers});
  }
```

And in job.ts

```
async getSavedJobs() {
    let id = await this.profileId();
    this.jobService.getSavedJobList(id).subscribe((list: any) => {
      for (let job of list) {
        this.savedjobs.push(job);
      }
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      console.log('err in getting the saved jobs '+ err);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this looks more correct, you don't subscribe inside of the genereal service component itself. But rather inside of the componenet you have your business logic. And where you use the data.